# using a vector B calculate the sum of the absolute differences of each element of B with every other element of B producing another array

Tags: matlab

So, for example, given:

```
B=[1:10]
```

`res` should be:

```
res =

    45 37 31 27 25 25 27 31 37 45
```

The first element of `res` is `45` because

```
|1-1| + |1-2| + ....+ |1-10| = 45
```

the second element is `37` because

```
|2-1| + |2-2| + ...+ |2-10| = 37
```

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,B,B')));
```

Output:

```
ans =

    45    37    31    27    25    25    27    31    37    45
```